# HTML 5 Input regex pattern not working as expected

Tags: html, regex

want to have a text field that only allows value between `${....} or 1 to 200` numeric value.

My regex is: `(\$\{(.*?)\}$)|(^([0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|200)$)`

Expected values are: ${abc}, 188, 22, etc..

I have checked this regex in https://regexr.com/ and it worked properly.
[image]

**However, when I add it to `pattern` it's not working as expected.**

```
<input pattern="(\$\{(.*?)\}$)|(^([0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|200)$)">
```

Comment: Input patterns are a HTML5 thing - are you using the correct HTML5  doctype declaration? <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: What does "not working as expected" mean? https://jsfiddle.net/6c8do2t3/ - seems to match your image's results.

Comment: @TiesonT. It allows all strings, does you jsfiddle not allowing wrong string? I opened your example and I can enter any string.

Comment: @gavgrif Yes I already have correct doctype

Comment: You can enter anything - that's how it's supposed to work. Values that don't match the pattern trigger the invalid state. Are you expecting it to prevent input?

Comment: Here's an example for showing how the `:invalid` state can be used: https://jsfiddle.net/6c8do2t3/1/ - if you want to prevent input, that requires JavaScript.